# `3n` distinct elements and finding two values, `x < y`?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, mergesort

This is an Interview Question I was asked yesterday. Can any expert verify for me which of the claims are True?

If we have an algorithm that give unsorted array with `3n` distinct elements and calculate two values, `x < y` such that `n` elements are lower than `x`, `n` elements are greater than `y`, and n elements are between `x` and `y`.

> claims A) there is an algorithm of `O(n)` average order for solving this
>   problem.
>
> claims B) there is an algorithm of `O(n)` order.
>
> claims C) with supposing `O(1)` additional storage in addition to input array, we couldn't solve this problem in a poly time.
>
> claims D) each algorithm that solve this problem has `Omega(n lg n)` order.

Comment: Did a clown conduct this interview with you in a circus? If he was not a clown then he is surely an imbicile.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it's so confusing...

Comment: Why do not ask simply whether you know the most efficient partition algorithm  for this task or not? Moreover if you do not know such an algorithm this says nothing about you as a programmer. It only means that you did not deal with such an algorithm.

Comment: This question would be improved by an example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has nothing interesting to say,  the answers have nothing interesting to say, and median-of-medians is extensively discussed on this site already.

Comment: @dfeuer, please be quite and just sing.

Answer (score 4):

There is `O(n)` time solution, using [**selection algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Find the `n+1`th smallest element and the `2n`th smallest element, these are the required elements that you seek.

Each invokation of selection algorithm is `O(n)` worst case (median of medians method), and you need 2 of those, so the complexity remains `O(n)`.

So,

- **claim B is correct, and also claim A** - both claims are satisfied by this algorithm, that has average+worst case time of `O(n)`.
- **Claim C is wrong**, because brute force solution of checking each pair
  of elements and iterating the array for each pair requires O(n^3)
  (polynomial) time, and O(1) space.
- **Claim D is wrong**, since the algorithm we suggested runs in O(n) time, and yet solves this problem, so there is an algorithm which is NOT `Omega(nlogn)` for this problem.

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang Claim A is obviously also correct if claim B is. Everything that satisfies claim A also satisfies claim B. The rest (C,D) are incorrect.

Comment: is it possible to take an example ?

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang Example of what? The proposed algorithm? It is based on selection algrotihm (which is out of scope to explain here, the wikipedia page I linked to is quite informative), and gets the relevant items immidiately.

Comment: @amit I don't think the Wikipedia page agrees with you. It says there is a *O(n)* solution for min and max, but an *O(nlogn)* solution for finding the *k*-th element: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Lower_bounds

Comment: @JonathanMee This is an upper bound, and not a tight one. The quick select algorithm has expected run time of O(n) because at each step you parition the array into two halves, and recurse on only one of them. This means the complexity function is `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)`, which is in `Theta(n)`

Comment: @JonathanMee As the article also states: `This bound is achievable for t=2 but better, more complex bounds are known for larger t.`, and particulary when `t` is in `Theta(n)`, it matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but as far as i can see, you'd need to sort the array `O(n log n)` and then you will easily partition it. 
So I guess claim D is correct?

Comment: Please prove your claim (that an O(n) solution does not exist). Obviously sorting solves it. Is it necessary though?

Comment: so its a linear search?

Comment: Not linear search, but linear time. Sorting is not needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is famous problem. If you know stl you can use `nth_element`. And you can see implementation in the `<algorithm>`.